# Cannot find the right tf_runtime wheel for Raspberry Pi 3B+, Python 3.10.2

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-3.10, tflite

Whenever I run the code:

```
tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=modelName)
```

The error is:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'lite'
```

I followed this [guide](https://qengineering.eu/install-tensorflow-2-lite-on-raspberry-pi-4.html) beforehand.

I tried adding contrib

```
tf.contrib.lite.Interpreter(model_path=modelName)
```

Didn't work

Also tried installing tflite_runtime but it says it doesn't support my platform

Comment: If there's no wheel for your platform, you're going to have to build it from source. That's the only answer.

Comment: @MattDMo That's fine. Are there any guides I can follow?